# How can I select only rows where a column is equal to any value from some list?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, dataset

Consider some data

```
data=Table[{RandomInteger[{0,10}],RandomReal[{0,1}]},10];
```

and some list

```
list={0,5,7,3};
```

How can I leave only the rows of `data` where the first column is equal to any of the values from `list`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = Table[{RandomInteger[{0, 10}], RandomReal[{0, 1}]}, 10];
list = {0, 5, 7, 3};

Cases[{Alternatives @@ list, _}] @ data
```

> ```
> {{5, 0.188274}, {7, 0.599774}, {3, 0.321288}, {3, 0.63921}}
> ```

Additional ways [`Alternatives`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) can be used for filtering `data`:

```
alt = Alternatives @@ list;

Pick[data, First /@ data, alt]

Select[MatchQ[{alt, _}]] @ data

DeleteCases[{Except @ alt, _}] @ data

ReplaceAll[{Except @ alt, _} -> Nothing] @ data
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = Table[{RandomInteger[{0, 10}], RandomReal[{0, 1}]}, 10];

Select[data, MemberQ[list, First@#] &]
```

OR

```
Pick[data, MemberQ[list, First@#] & /@ data]
```

OR

```
DeleteCases[data, _?(FreeQ[First@#, Alternatives @@ list] &)]
```

OR

```
Extract[data, Position[data[[All, 1]], Alternatives @@ list]]
```

OR

```
Select[data, IntersectingQ[{First@#}, list] &]
```

OR

```
Pick[data, IntersectingQ[{First@#}, list] & /@ data]
```

OR

```
Select[data, ContainsAny[{First@#}, list] &]
```

---

> {{5, 0.188274}, {7, 0.599774}, {3, 0.321288}, {3, 0.63921}}

Answer (score 5):

Using `GroupBy` and `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[data, ! FreeQ[list, First@#] &], True]
```

Or suggested by @NonDairyNeutrino:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[data, MemberQ[list, First@#] &], True]

(*Thanks, NonDairyNeutrino!*)

(*{{5, 0.402035}, {5, 0.592331}, {3, 0.99012}}*)
```

Comment: I believe `!FreeQ` can be simplified to `MemberQ`.